# Firestore document deletion via Firebase Console

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-firestore

When I delete a document in a Firestore database using Firebase Console I always get read operations as well. Is it because with every delete action taken, the view in the console is fetching another batch of data from the collection from which the document has been deleted from?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> When I delete a document in a Firestore database using Firebase Console I always get read operations as well.

That's the expected behavior since when you open the Firebase Console, you're reading documents. The Firebase Console is considered a client, like any other web, Android, or iOS client. So you have to pay for the reads that are coming from the console as well.

However, if you delete the data programmatically, you'll not have to pay for any reads. A delete operation is **not** tied in any way to a read operation.